# ArchiveDescriptor reused; can URLs be processed multiple times?

Tags: jboss7.x

I am trying to migrate application from jboss6.2 to jboss7.1.4. Getting this error during deployment. Please let me know if anyone has got this error before:

> 15:23:45,400 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation]
>   (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYCTL0013: Operation ("deploy") failed -
>   address: ([("deployment" => "lms-package-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.ear")]) -
>   failure description: {"WFLYCTL0080: Failed services" => {
>       "jboss.persistenceunit.\"lms-package-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.ear/lms-presentation-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war#lmsDS\".**FIRST_PHASE**"
>   => "java.lang.IllegalStateException: ArchiveDescriptor reused; can URLs be processed multiple times?
>       Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: ArchiveDescriptor reused; can URLs be processed multiple times?",
>       "jboss.persistenceunit.\"lms-package-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.ear/lms-presentation-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war#rmsxDS\".**FIRST_PHASE**"
>   => "java.lang.IllegalStateException: ArchiveDescriptor reused; can URLs be processed multiple times?
>       Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: ArchiveDescriptor reused; can URLs be processed multiple times?"

Answer (score 0):

Resolved. In persistence.xml , removed this line:

lms-domain-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar

Could be some compatibility issue with Wildfly7.1.4